# How do you determine the DB resource type?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, resources

I have a link to a db resource, but in some cases i get a mysql link and in some other cases  the functions get a postgresql resource type.

Depending on the connection type, I need to do different things. How can I test the type of the connection?

In some cases I need to use `$res = pg_query($link, $sqlcmd)`
and in some other cases I need to use something like `mysql_query`.

Any suggestions?

I tried already `get_class` and `get_type`.

Comment: You should switch to PDO to make the code more independent of the database engine.

Comment: Are working on it. But the code is gigantic. And im responsible for legacy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [`get_resource_type()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php). It returns the [resource type](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php).

For example:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
if(get_resource_type($res) == 'mysql result') {
    // mysql result
} elseif(get_resource_type($res) == 'pgsql result') {
    // pgsql result
}
```